# C++ ofstream create and write file issue

Tags: c++, std, filestream

i had problem with my virtual file system extractor.

```
ofstream ofs(path, ios::out|ios::binary);

ofs.write(file, length);
ofs.close();
```

Path is for a example "data/char/actormotion.txt", and there should be created file in directory data/char/ file named actormotion.txt but there is done nothing.

Comment: What is a `virtual file system extractor`? Perhaps there is more relevant code. Could you manage a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Also, debug, run under `strace` (permission issues?) check for disk full etc.

Comment: use ofs.open() to open a file.

Comment: @mari0-k bullocks, the [constructor calls that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream).

Comment: @mari0-k Doing it through the constructor is another alternative.

Comment: I would make sure the directory `"data/char/"` exists first before you try to create a file there.

Comment: @sehe virtual file system is just packed all files into one like a archive without compression.

Comment: @jxh it's possible to autocreate ? but this file system had 20 000 files in different dirs.

Comment: It is not `ofstream`s job to create a directory, just the file. If the directory doesn't exist, it will fail when trying to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that it is open first

```
      std::ofstream ofs(path, ios::out|ios::binary);
      if (ofs.is_open())
      {
// write stuff
        ofs.close();
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout << "Error opening file";
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

More likely file wasn't opened. You may check this with `bool is_open()` method.

After opening stream is advisable check its state to make sure everything going well:

```
ofstream ofs(path, ios::out|ios::binary);
if ( (ofs.rdstate() & std::ofstream::failbit ) != 0 ){
    //stream opened successfully, do the stuff...
```

in Windows system you may call `GetLastError()` right after to query error code.

Comment: Or `if (ofs.fail())`.

Comment: The C++ Standard Library does not call `SetLastError`. Calling `GetLastError` after a C++ Standard Library call fails will not return anything meaningful.